# Frequency Domain Equalization [Sources request]

Tags: frequency-domain

When I read papers, I often see the term "[Frequency Domain Equalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-carrier_FDMA)".

I do not understand what a "frequency domain equalizer" is.

Do they mean equalizers like MMSE, LMMSE?

Or is there an equalizer called FDE?

Comment: How did you learn about FDEs in the first place? Can you link to a reference that told you about them?

Comment: I read a paper that used "frequency domain equalization" as a means to mitigate ISI. @PeterK.

Comment: i edited the question @PeterK.